# Question about trend and predictions in R

Tags: r, time-series, lm

I have weekly data which I am considering as reference. So Mondays trend for example.. orders will kind of serve as valid data to make predictions for orders throughout the day for every Monday. I looked at the `lm()` and `predict()` functions in R, but it seems that they just predict based my previous data model. They don't take into account the level of orders on the current Monday. So I can't blindly use the prediction obtained from the historical model. What I want is that the algorithm refers to previous data for trend but also considers the current levels and then makes the prediction.

Is there any way to do that? Or maybe am I looking at the wrong models?

Comment: What i really want is that my new predictions follow a pattern (levels could be different) closely.. So if the origin is shifted, my predictions should follow historical observations. Any leads would be appreciated.

Comment: You're using orders to predict orders and you want to incorporate the most recent data? That would be updating the model.

Comment: This might be a case for Kalman filter, search this site!